# rails collection_select vs. select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`collection_select` and `select` Rails helpers: Which one should I use?

I can't see a difference in both ways. Both helpers take a collection and generates options tags inside a select tag. Is there a scenario where `collection_select` is better than `select`? or is anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 79):

`collection_select` is intended to be used when the list of items is an array of ActiveRecord objects. `collection_select` is built on the top of `select` so it's a convenient method when you need to display a collection of objects and not an array of strings.

```
collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.find(:all), :id, :name)
```

Comment: This is clearly the right answer and deserves acceptance. what gives @webnuwan?

Comment: Thank, great answer.  Now bigger question though, why isn't that tidbit included in the Rails ActionView::Helpers API guide?

Answer (score 1):

I have written something on that a while back, have a look at
http://nasir.wordpress.com/2007/11/02/not-binding-your-selection-list-to-a-particular-model-in-rails/

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

And regarding `select`, you can use it with a **Hash**. I used to use it with ENUM.

```
# In a hypothetical Fruit model
enum types: { 'Banana' => 0, 'Grape' => 1, 'Mango' => 2 }

# In the view
f.select :type, Fruits.types.invert
```

Note that I had to use **invert** in order to show the correct value in option:

```
<select>
  <option value="0">Banana</option>
  <option value="1">Grape<option>
  <option value="2">Mango</option>
</select>
```

To refer to it in a show file you can use `Fruit.types` and this will return our previous Hash. This way you can do:

```
 Fruit.types[obj.type]
```

**Last note:** You can use symbols instead numbers if you prefer `enum types: { 'Banana' => :banana, ...`and you will get `<option value="banana">Banana</option>`