# How to generate a dropdown in Rails 5, what's the idiomatic way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

There're many ways to create a drop down in Rails. And it's not clear why there're so many and which one is idiomatic.

I'm using Rails 5x and the built-in form helper.

```
  <%= form_for(@my_model, :url => some_url(@my_model)) do |f| %>
    <%= f. # ?? f.select ?? f.collection_select ?? or anything else?
```

What's the idiomatic and recommended way?

Note that I don't want to use an external gem such as simple_form.

Comment: It's mostly a question about where will you store your options list for this dropdown?

Comment: Not sure why people down voted this question. Michael Arkhipov is the best answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Select - for basic usage. 
For example, in this case you need to add value manually:

```
<%= f.select(:name, :some_id, [['Emma', 1], ['Oliver', 2]) %>
```

But if you have model with data for this value, you can use collection_select:

```
<%= collection_select(:something, :id, User.all, :some_id, :name) %>
```

**Update**

Example for your comment:

```
<%= options_for_select(
  [
    ['Emma', 1, { 'data-attr' => '200ms' }],
    ['Oliver', 2, { 'data-attr' => '400ms' }]
  ], 2 # selected options id
) %>
```

HTML Result:

```
<option value="1" data-attr="200ms">Emma</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected" data-attr="400ms">Oliver</option>
```

Comment: what's `options_for_select` for?

Comment: @Joddy you can add arbitrary attributes and set "selected" for option. Check answer again, i added an example.

Answer (score 0):

`collection_select` is intended to be used when the list of items is an array of ActiveRecord objects. `collection_select` is built on the top of `select` so it's a convenient method when you need to display a collection of objects and not an array of strings.

You may refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728593/rails-collection-select-vs-select) for detailed answer.